# Casting int to nat in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

How can I cast an int to nat in Isabelle when I'm sure that it is positive?

```
value "((-10)::int) mod 3"
```

for example gives 2 and if I'm correct any application of modulo on an int should result in a nat.

Unfortunately the type signature of modulo is `'a => 'a => 'a` so I cannot fix 3 to a nat beforehand and the result will be an int.

Comment: `value "nat (((-10)::int) mod 3)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `value "nat (((-10)::int) mod 3)"`.